# pyinstaller generate exe on mac

Tags: python, windows, macos, pyinstaller, converters

Is there a way to compile a .py file +additional data MAC to a .exe?

auto-py-to-exe is working great when I do in on my windows laptop.

But I often work on mac when I am not at home and need to compile my .py + some other folders and files to .exe

But when I try it on MAC I always only get a MAC executable file, not for windows.

Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Yes doing on mac will get you a mac file always ,because there is something like a platform check when pyinstaller is used. I dont think there is a way to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

[from pyinstaller FAQ section](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ)

> **Can I package Windows binaries while running under OS X?**
> *No, this is not supported. Please try [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) for this.*

Comment: thanks my problem is not to actually open .exe files on MAC but rather compile my .py to exe when I am on MAC. If I understand Wine correct, this is just an emulator?

Comment: That's exactly what the FAQ entry is about. Read it again - Can I PACKAGE Windows binaries while running under OS X? Their advise is to run Wine, install python for Windows + pyinstaller and try to package the exe inside Wine.